# Mediawiki custom namespaces id change

Tags: namespaces, mediawiki, identifier

I am currently working on an internal Mediawiki and we are using a lot of **custom written extensions**. 
Because we did no know better, defined custom namespaces for our own extensions and articles with an id that is **smaller than 3000**.

For example:

```
define('NS_bla', 1100);
$wgExtraNamespaces[NS_bla] = "bla";
define('NS_bla_TALK', 1101);
$wgExtraNamespaces[NS_bla_TALK] = "bla Talk";
```

We did this with several different extensions. Now we read on the official documentation (http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension_default_namespaces) that custom namespaces **should use id's that are 3000+**.

Therefore my question: How can we easily **change the IDs of the namespaces** on the  production instance, without messing up with our current dataset? How could we tackle this problem? I could not find any information on the Mediawiki documentation.

Thank's a lot in advance and

Cheers from Germany,

Fabian

Comment: Are the namespace ID's causing a conflict? Or are you trying to publish your extensions for others to use, and just want to make sure it fits the guidelines?

Comment: Hi jlerney, thank's a lot for your quick answer! The ID's are not causing any conflicts yet - if so we sould just change manually. We would like to follow the mediawiki guidelines. That's currently the only purpose ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question, you would need to update the page table with the new namespace ID:

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Using_custom_namespaces#Use_a_database_query

To fit this to your occassion, it would be:

```
UPDATE page 
SET page_namespace = 3000
WHERE page_namespace = 1100
```

You shouldn't have to replace the page_title since these articles are already in another namespace.

Just please remember to back up your database before trying this.

Comment: There are several fields which store namespace numbers and need to be updated: `archive.ar_namespace`, `watchlist.wl_namespace`, `logging.log_namespace` plus whatever your extensions add. Also the links tables (`pagelinks`, `templatelinks`, `imagelinks`, `categorylinks`, `iwlinks`) and `recentchanges`, although those can just be regenerated.